# OSX boot2docker trouble connecting to docker daemon

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker, iterm2

Totally new to docker. Trying to learn. I followed the [docker guide for mac osx](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/) and have had nothing but trouble. I am on OSX 10.9.4. boot2docker & docker v1.5.0. My VirtualBox is version 4.3.26 (just upgraded). I can get to the point of running `docker run hello-world`. I get the error `FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?`. Also the command `$(boot2docker shellinit)` produces the error `error in run: Error requesting socket: exit status 2`, so I have to export each manually, which seems fine. I can grep my env and see all of them in my profile. I've been all over stack overflow and googling around and have tried numerous approaches to try and resolve this, but can not seem to find any that have worked for me up to this point. I wanted to reach out and see if anyone else had some suggestions on how to reach the docker daemon? Happy to provide more verbose details about my set up or versions, just let me know what I can provide to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how I can add my user to the docker group? I'm searching around and seem to be having trouble. I think this may be related. Not sure, figured it was worth a shot. Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need to worry about the docker group if you're using boot2docker. I've not seen this error though.

Comment: Hmmm...... it's possible I might not need to. I've just had more than one person tell me that was the issue right off the bat without hesitation. And even mentioned that they struggled with the same issue. Though this was just over casual conversation and they did not dive into many details. This was the only reason I explored this as a possible reason to my issue. Can you think of any other reasons why I might see this error?

Comment: I am seeing the exact same problem on my windows machine. It worked on Virtualbox 4.3.20 before (having a network issue there). After upgrading to 4.3.26 it fails. See https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/745

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is download the latest version of the Boot2docker, then reinstall the boot2docker. It will downgrade the Virtualbox to the compatible version.